# Using bash to clip a number to upper and lower limits

Tags: bash

I am extracting user ratings after making some calculations. If calculated rating exceeds 5.0 (say 5.001), I want to clip it to 5 and if it falls below 1 (say 0.001), I want to limit it to 1.

I will be grateful if there can be a bash script that makes this clipping.  Or maybe I can use a python script from command line which takes dollar variable from bash.

Comment: Where are you getting these ratings from? Are you taking them as input in shell?

Comment: `bash` arithmetic doesn't support fractions, only whole numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use awk:

```
awk '$0<1{$0=1}$0>5{$0=5}1' <<<"$var"
```

If the variable is less than 1, change it to 1. If it is greater than 5, change it to 5. `1` at the end is always true, so awk performs the default action, which is to print the record.

Some additional explanation:

- `<<<` is an alternative way of writing `echo "$var" | awk ...`, supported by bash
- `$0` refers to the current "record", which in this case is the variable that has been echoed to bash
- awk works like `condition { action }`, so each block is only run if the condition before it is true
- if no `{action}` part is specified, the default action is `{print}`, so that's what the `1` at the end does.

For example:

```
$ var=0.001
$ awk '$0<1{$0=1}$0>5{$0=5}1' <<<"$var"
1
$ var=5.001
$ awk '$0<1{$0=1}$0>5{$0=5}1' <<<"$var"
5
```

To overwrite the variable, you can use command substitution:

```
var=$(awk '$0<1{$0=1}$0>5{$0=5}1' <<<"$var")
```

If you like confusing yourself, you can do the same thing using two ternary operators instead:

```
awk '{$0=$0<1?1:$0>5?5:$0}1' <<<"$var"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to untie the knots and trying to understand how it works. Kindly do make it little simpler, if possible.

Comment: I've added some more explanation, hopefully that helps

Comment: @user3282777 no problem. Don't forget to accept answers to your questions by clicking on the tick ✔ next to them.